# Scrolling voting buttons

Tags: discussion, voting, a-b-testing

The voting buttons scrolling for the question is very disorienting. It even happens for answers. Can I have that turned off?

The `div.vote` gets the class `js-vote-sticky` attached to it.

It looks something like this:

> [image]

Comment: I'm seeing consistent similar behavior for answers as well.  I'm using Chrome 43 on Windows 7.

Comment: @Daniel, could you elaborate on what you are seeing exactly?

Comment: on the main site, the voting buttons to the left of a question/answer are flowing down into the whitespace next to the comment area on scroll.

Comment: No repro here on Firefox, even after reload-bypass-cache. What's your browser?

Comment: chrome latest windows. its a script thing that i might be in a limited test.

Comment: Yup, possibly it's A/B testing. In that case, someone else will eventually chime in with the same problem.

Comment: Something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/SzCQrZn.png)?  This is happening for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651831/integrating-a-running-clock-in-my-program-c-sharp), but not others I've visited.

Comment: I'm seeing it and I'm getting very dizzy.

Comment: @ryanyuyu yep exactly.

Comment: not to mention when one click on the vote to close option, the popup menu for it, veered severely over to the left, cutting off 1/2 the menu for it. Edit: I retested with another question (not closing it of course) and now it appears to have come back to its normal state. However, there is a big blank block between the arrows/votes and **This question already has an answer here:**

Comment: update to above ^ - that empty block seems to have disappeared.

Comment: @Fred-ii- looks like someone else [posted this specific symptom](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296082/possible-bug-with-scrolling-voting-button-a-b-test).

Comment: thanks @ryanyuyu seems like Stack's overgoing some form of change. I'll follow that, thanks again, *cheers*

Comment: I just got this, cannot look at the questions or answers, just staring at that button o_0

Comment: I feel sad looking at all this bad feedback when I haven't had the chance to try it out....

Comment: @NathanTuggy It's not really that bad, takes some getting used to, but after a while its along the same lines as the flashing favicon when editing an answer, meanwhile I clicked the checkbox for the new navigation a week or so ago and still haven't gotten it :(

Comment: @humble.rumble: Yeah, new-nav was ... funky. I gave up on that for now, but since I like the idea here a lot, I really want to see how it actually pans out for myself.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I'm probably making it out to be more than it is. I'm sure if it had been here when I first started I wouldn't have had an issue with it. I'm still not sure if it is useful yet, or just moar majick

Comment: [Downvote without comment notification doesn't show up properly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296130/downvote-without-comment-notification-doesnt-show-up-properly)

Comment: @NathanTuggy I'm getting used to it now and it's starting to feel more useful having it there

Comment: I think I dislike this feature, but not sure if that's just because I'm resistant to change!

Comment: How to get rid of the floating buttons using Adblock? Better have no voting at all than this!

Comment: Personally I love it. This is superb UX imho.

Comment: Announcement on Meta Stack Exchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258048/a-b-testing-the-sticky-vote-controls-give-your-feedback-please

Answer (score 64):

I feel my eyes were caught by the floating scrolling voting buttons rather than focusing on the post and reading the question itself. It is visually distracting and disturbing for users. Keep It Simple & Stupid (KISS) is the fundamental principle in programming philosophy as well as on Stack Overflow. I vote for removing the scrolling voting button and restoring the original view for simplicity and beauty.

Comment: I wish I could +10 this

Comment: 200% agreed. That floating scrolling voting buttons are pain in eyes.

Comment: This was an interesting experiment with a good intention, and it looks like it was nicely done, but, after a few hours of use I also vote for a removal. Even a serial voter like me can scroll a little and **there's a lot of value in having a page looking like a frozen sheet of paper** : much less effort to do to track what happens, you don't have to scroll, look then act, all the acts are instantly planned.

Answer (score 36):

We're running an [A/B test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) on a [proposed change to voting controls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35041/move-the-vote-button/254795#254795).

Currently, the controls will move when you can vote on a post.  For example, as an answerer, the voting controls will not move on your answers; the same is true for question askers and their questions.

Here's a [feedback thread on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257910/dont-move-vote-buttons-past-the-bottom-of-the-post) addressing some of the functionality.

Comment: [Downvote without comment notification doesn't show up properly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296130/downvote-without-comment-notification-doesnt-show-up-properly)

Comment: One issue I have with this feature is that while voting should be emphasized, the floating vote-me-now! button is now very in your face, is moving and as a result your eye constantly tracks to it, and detracts from being able to read the content of the actual post. While answering a question it makes it slightly harder to concentrate on the content of the post because there is the constant and insistent voting mechanism "following" you around like a stalker. Vote me! And even if you do vote, it is still there, reminding you of your vote.

Comment: There's no request for feedback at the linked post. It's a request for a modification related to movement. The feedback for the feature itself should have its own post, where we can vote on the addition of the functionality rather than tweaks. I personally dislike it immensely, and would be extremely in favor of an option to disable it. The popup if you try to vote inappropriately works. Where's the usual post announcing that this will be in testing and asking for actual feedback for the "feature" specifically?

Comment: @KenWhite you're correct and I apologize - here's a [meta post where you can give feedback](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258048/a-b-testing-the-sticky-vote-controls-give-your-feedback-please).  I've fixed the popup message display that may show when you submit a vote.

Comment: *For example, as an answerer, the voting controls will not move on your answers* - I just observed it the other way around: Having answered a question the buttons moved on my fresh answer but *not* on the question.

Answer (score 6):

I guess it's a matter of personal taste, I personally find it distracting, but I understand why some might find this useful. Either way, there should definitely be an option for the users to disable this.

Comment: Or, contrariwise, an option to enable it. ;)

Comment: It's useful when the post is very long. But when the post is small or medium sized, probably 10-40 lines, it's not useful.

Answer (score 5):

I don't really mind the change, but if you find it distracting, all you need to do is inject the following CSS in your browser.

```
.js-vote-sticky {
    position: static !important;
}
```

Here is a user script that will do just that.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Stack Exchange Voting Static
// @namespace   stack-exchange-voting-static
// @description Prevents fixed position voting buttons on Stack Exchange.
// @include     /^https?\:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?((stackexchange|stackoverflow|serverfault|superuser|askubuntu|stackapps)\.com|mathoverflow\.net)\//
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

if (document.head) {
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.textContent = '.js-vote-sticky { position: static !important; }';
    document.head.appendChild(style);
}
```

<sup>(Yes, I know the feature is currently only enabled on Stack Overflow, but I've added the other domains for good measure.)</sup>

I've tested it with Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey, but it may also work with other user script implementations.

---

One minor critique about the feature, if the browser window scrolls horizontally, for example if the window is too narrow, the buttons will float on top of the content.

Answer (score 2):

Am I the only one who liked this feature ?

I know this changes from person to person, but I have definitely not found it distracting;

I also guess it's useful for new users who don't remember to accept/upvote...
Not a big change in short answers, but pretty useful in long ones.

Comment: I want it back!