# Possible bug with scrolling voting button A/B Test

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, closed-questions, a-b-testing

I know that there is a [scrolling voting button A/B Test is in progress](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35041/move-the-vote-button/254795#254795).

However, I'm seeing some inconsistency due to this(?).

see the screenshot, there is some unwanted space introduced.

Is it a bug?

[image]

Or, see [live](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30615960/2173917).

Info: Running on Chrome 43+, Windows 8.1.

Comment: yeah, I saw that too earlier, and then it disappeared then reappeared again. Not to mention the vote to close popup box options being thrown severely over to the left. They're probably trying to get the CSS just right ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed now, sorry!