# Downvote without comment notification doesn't show up properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, notifications, a-b-testing

This is a bug report for [Move the vote button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35041/move-the-vote-button) which is currently in [A/B testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) on Stack Overflow.

Today I tried to downvote question which is lengthy in size. So I've scrolled down to read and decided to downvote it. So I've got Downvote without comment notification like below.

[image]

Steps to reproduce issue.

1. Take lengthy question.
2. Scroll it down.
3. Click on down vote.

**I think it should show up like below to keep consistent everywhere.**

[image]

Comment: It stops showing up for those of us over a certain rep threshold.  What specifically were you seeing that's wrong?  Is it that the size appears a little squished?

Comment: @Makoto Please check my edit

Comment: [The same happens for other popups as well](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zfYxv.gif)

Comment: @CoolGuy Thank you for adding image.

Comment: @Makoto The feature is in A/B testing (i.e. shown to a random subset of users) since yesterday so you might not be seeing it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35041/move-the-vote-button

Comment: @Gilles: I'm in the split test; I just haven't seen that message in a ***long*** time.  So, I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 17):

I recreated this problem :)

### The Cause

#### Before the vote buttons stick to the top of the viewport

`td.votecell` has been given `position: relative` so the `position: absolute` `div.message` is now confined to the thin table cell.

#### After the sticky buttons stick to the top of the viewport

The `div.vote` is now given the inline style of `position: fixed` so the `div.message` is now confined within the thin div.

### The simple fix

Give the `.message` div `white-space: nowrap` so that it overflows:

> [image: Fixed :)]

---

### Bonus!

I changed the padding of `div.message-close` (the `x` close button) to `padding: 2px 4px 0px 4px` and I swear that it looks better.

Comment: Now, popups look like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G5aD9.jpg) to me, regardless of scrolling. [Another popup too](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o9lrc.jpg)