# Can we make the answer score and up/downvote buttons sticky so it scrolls with you for long answers?

Tags: feature-request, design, voting, user-interface, user-experience

Currently, if I'm reading a long answer and by the end of it decide it was a good one and is worth an upvote (or the other way around and a downvote), I need to scroll all the way back up to the start of the answer to do that. If the answer is really long, this is hella annoying.

Can we please make the score count with the vote arrows sticky, so it scrolls down with you as you read the answer, so you don't have to go back up to upvote or downvote? Quora has something similar and it doesn't look that bad IMHO.

Comment: I feel like there's a smell about of seeing a really long answer that would beget this kind of scrolling.  What about on mobile when the screen real estate is such that almost *every* answer has to scroll?  What would that mean for users in that state?  (Yes, I'm one of those users)

Comment: Personally, I prefer the vote block as you describe this (well, I actually prefer it to follow down the page and then move to the mouse when I move the mouse into vote column). I make that change for myself via userscript in my personal modifications. I've also seen other users mention they use a userscript to do as you've described. There's "[Floating vote buttons (script)](https://stackapps.com/q/7999/29529)", which if modified as described in the comments, will do this.

Comment: @Makoto I just checked, and on Android mobile you already give up the screen real estate for the voting block column for every answer, scrolling or no. With a sticky voting block, you at least have something to act on in that real estate. Now, if you think we could convince them to float the voting block and wrap the answer around it, that might be an interesting proposal...

Answer (score 7):

I would *love* to see this added to vanilla Stack Overflow/ Exchange; posts just don't have to be that long for the vote arrows to be out of view by the time you get to the bottom.

It feels worthwhile to add that there is an existing userscript which includes this feature (among others), from SO moderator [@Samuel Liew](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/584192/samuel-liew), called [Post Headers and Question TOC](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md#post-headers--question-toc) (part of their [larger collection](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts#stack-overflow-moderation-userscripts) of scripts, lots of *very* useful gems in there).

To the contrary of complaints that it would be distracting, I find the floating arrows extremely *un*obtrusive, to the point that it feels like a vanilla site feature, and I miss them dearly when I browse without them. They make very sensible use of the otherwise vacant vertical column of space below the static voting arrows.

Here's how it looks in use on [a medium-length FAQ meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146):

> [image: Demo of the Question Headers & TOC userscript]

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a pretty good idea. You can achieve a roughly complete implementation of this (not the prettiest at the bottom, but not bad, either) with the following styles in a user script of your own:

```css
#answers .votecell .js-voting-container {
    position: sticky;
    top: 100px;
}
```

Ideally, if implemented at the site-level, the devs would make it stop scrolling at the bottom of the post body rather than the entire post container (since `.votecell` includes the height of the usercard, etc.). And it would only be applied if the answer is longer than the viewport.

Comment: you don't need position:relative. unlike absolute or fixed, sticky doesn't require relative on the parent element. Its containing block is defined like for a static or relative element.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, that's what I had thought, but it didn't work for me until I added it. My browser's dev tools have been pretty laggy lately, though, so maybe that was the cause... I didn't want to restart the whole thing just to test that one property :-)

Answer (score -1):

Please don't. Elements that scroll along with the content to stay in view are very distracting.

It's been tried and removed in the past: [Scrolling voting buttons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296078/scrolling-voting-buttons)

Comment: that didn't stop the sticky header from sticking around

Comment: I think that's still a setting that you can disable, and it's a fixed element spanning the whole width of the page.

Comment: they removed that setting a while ago, "because most people used the default setting"

Comment: Here's a somewhat low-quality gif of what it would like https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-b52884b1b9.gif Not really that distracting, IMHO (though whether it's worth it is another matter).

Comment: _"Not really that distracting, IMHO"_ - yeah, well, that's just, like, your opinion, man. I really don't like it. ;)

Comment: The response to the prior implementation isn't valid for a current evaluation (it should be noted, but not considered valid). That implementation was done in 2015. Chrome didn't support `position sticky` until version 56, which was released in 2017. That means the 2015 implementation would have been done in JavaScript. Doing a "sticky" implementation in JavaScript is tricky and usually looks poor, *at best*, if not *terrible*. Using CSS with `position sticky` is *worlds* different as to how it looks and feels to users, so I'd expect a *substantially* different response to such feature.

Comment: That doesn't mean everyone's going to like it, just that the response to the prior implementation shouldn't be weighted all that heavily when evaluating if this feature would be desired by users. Personally, I'd hate a JavaScript implementation of this, while I actually like a CSS `position sticky` implementation.

Comment: @Makyen I don't care about the implementation, I just don't like floating stuff on a page that scrolls along.

Comment: @Makyen Yeah no definitely JavaScript implementation would suck for a bunch of different reasons, I did meant for it to be via CSS' `position: sticky`.

Comment: Same here. I indeed want such elements to be sticky - stick to their place that is. I'm already bothered enough by friggin' ads starting to float along as you scroll a page on a mobile, we need less of that terrible design. I also think it has somewhat of a secondary function that you kind of have to scroll to get to the voting buttons, it gives you a moment of pause. Kind of similar to individually wrapped candies. If you get a bag of candies without wrappers, you're going to be likely eating many more of them due to there being no moment of pause and reflection to get to each individual one.

Comment: @Gimby And that is a good thing? I think people should be voting more, not be dissuaded by long scrolling and not voting at all. Also, your candy metaphor isn't quite working, as I would eat them all wrapper or no wrapper. :D